# How to format <asp:textbox type=date /> to specific date format while page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have asp:textbox type=date and i want to retrieve date from sql
and i would like to format the textbox as i want and ignore client pc format

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDate" class="form-control" type="date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are retrieving date from a `SQL table`....hold it in data table....and set into `Textbox`....

```
TextBoxDate.Text = string.Format("{0:mm-dd-yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Date"])));
```

If you want to set current date to textbox then set this line in code behind in page load

```
TextBoxDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```